# Does this script have anything that would conflict with other javascript on my page?

Tags: javascript, window, onload

I am not quite sure what is going on. I create a fresh html page and set up this JS snippet I found and it works. I apply it to my IPB Forum and it doesn't work at all. Could there be anything here that could conflict with other javascript on my page? Is there any no conflict code I should try to add to accompany this JS snippet? I am fairly new to JS so I could use all the help I could get.

```
    window.onload = function(){
//canvas init
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//canvas dimensions
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

//snowflake particles
var mp = 25; //max particles
var particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
{
    particles.push({
        x: Math.random()*W, //x-coordinate
        y: Math.random()*H, //y-coordinate
        r: Math.random()*4+1, //radius
        d: Math.random()*mp //density
    })
}

//Lets draw the flakes
function draw()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
    {
        var p = particles[i];
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    }
    ctx.fill();
    update();
}

//Function to move the snowflakes
//angle will be an ongoing incremental flag. Sin and Cos functions will be applied to it to create vertical and horizontal movements of the flakes
var angle = 0;
function update()
{
    angle += 0.01;
    for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
    {
        var p = particles[i];
        //Updating X and Y coordinates
        //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards
        //Every particle has its own density which can be used to make the downward movement different for each flake
        //Lets make it more random by adding in the radius
        p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.d) + 1 + p.r/2;
        p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;

        //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
        //Lets make it a bit more organic and let flakes enter from the left and right also.
        if(p.x > W+5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H)
        {
            if(i%3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
            {
                particles[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: -10, r: p.r, d: p.d};
            }
            else
            {
                //If the flake is exitting from the right
                if(Math.sin(angle) > 0)
                {
                    //Enter from the left
                    particles[i] = {x: -5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
                }
                else
                {
                    //Enter from the right
                    particles[i] = {x: W+5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//animation loop
setInterval(draw, 33);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible `window.onload` is being re-defined in your other javascript code?

Comment: I will look it over when I get a chance and I will post an update. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. Appears to have been an issue with the css that wasn't allowing it to show up properly. But now I am running into a new issue...Does anyone know a way to make negative z-index work in Google Chrome? I gave this effect a negative value so it would be behind all the content but it screws with google chrome. All other browsers work great. I don't want to go and add a positive z-index value to every element I have on my site...

Comment: Update: I used a positive z-index value for this canvas and put a wrapper around the rest of the content with position: relative; Works like a charm now.

Comment: Feel free to answer and accept your own question.